# Code by Zapier - Splitting a string with integers and text with multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, zapier

I am a total JS newbie, and am struggling with pulling sub-strings of data that has multiple delimiters.

Input: 404327 - Muskoka Cream Ale 6pack,131490 - Muskoka Cream Ale Cans 442673 - Muskoka Winterweiss,404368 - Muskoka Detour

I need to take that string and split it with "-" delimitting product# from name, and "," seperating products.

Desired Output
Sku-A: 404327
Name A: Muskoka Cream Ale 6pack
Sku-B: 131490 
Name-B: Muskoka Cream Ale Cans
Sku-C: 442673
Name-C: Muskoka Winterweiss
Sku-D: 404368 
Name D:Muskoka Detour

Comment: You should include what code you've written and tried. Also, there are no "Sku's" in the input, are these required in the output?

Comment: Sorry, new to asking questions here as well. The "Skus" are the integers in the Input (ie 404327).

Comment: Here is the code I have tried:

var testString = '404335 - Muskoka Detour, 419671 - Muskoka Summerweiss';
testString.split(',')                    // ["404335 - Muskoka Detour", " 419671 - Muskoka Summerweiss"]
testString.split(',')[0]                //  "404335 - Muskoka Detour"
testString.split(',')[0].split(' - ') // ["404335", "Muskoka Detour"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested splits, one for the products and later to separate id and name.

```js
var string = '404327 - Muskoka Cream Ale 6pack,131490 - Muskoka Cream Ale Cans,442673 - Muskoka Winterweiss,404368 - Muskoka Detour',
    products = string.split(',').map(function (a) {
        var parts = a.split(' - ');
        return { id: parts[0], name: parts[1] };
    });

console.log(products);
```